# text on right side of image in container (multiple images)

Tags: html, css, image, text, css-float

im making a container that contains 3 images and three "text bits"

My problem is that I cant seem to get the text to appear on the right side of each image. 
Here a SS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjcGg.jpg

The html:

```
        <div class="textandimg">
        <div class="image">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="img/belahotellforside.png" alt="belahotellforside">
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
        <p>asdfer</p>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="img/caprocatforside.png" alt="caprocatforside">
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
        <p>asdfer</p>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="img/granhotellforside.png" alt="granhotellforside">
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
        <p>asdfer</p>
        </div>



 </div>
```

and the css:

```
.textandimage{
clear:both;
}
.image{
float:left;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 10px;
}
.text{
float:left;
}
```

If I put :

```
.text{
 float:right;
 }
```

The text appears on the right side. But its still inline with the picture. And I want the text to be side by side.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all that CSS and just put this:

```
.image{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

All you want is just to `float` the images to the left of the text `divs`, so that's all you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/M8CQD/

Edit: From your comment, it also looks like you need to put each `image` and `text` div together in a `div` in order to push the `images` down below the preceding image.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="image">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/belahotellforside.png" alt="belahotellforside">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>asdfer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I only have the images to float left, this happens: http://imgur.com/53Zb3U6 wich is really weird. If i just remove the text the images just lay side by side horizontal as long there is room in the containter.

Answer (score 0):

If your div with `image` class has setted `width: 100%` it take 100% of the width. So you can remove it or set to an value in "px".